# nodejs, passport, google and an API

Tags: node.js, api, passport.js, passport-google-oauth

How do you authentication multiple websites through a single `NodeJS` API using `passport`'s google authentication strategy?

The API is hosted separately to the webpages. From playing with the guides on the `passport` website and tutorials I can find, they all rely on the `Node` application doing the page rendering (i.e. using `Jade` etc) and not passing a token back to a separate web application

What is the best approach for creating a single API that can authenticate against `Google` and return a token to the client without having the API and the website(s) hosted on the same box and all served by `NodeJS`?

I can get the strategy to work when accessing the API endpoints directly, but I cannot figure out how an application would interact with those, and get a token back when they are on different domains.